# codeigniter sessions not carrying from page to page

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, cookies

Is anyone here familiar with CodeIgniter sessions? 
I have a login script which is functional. On a successful login, a session is created. A user is redirected to thier home page. The new page should show thier username as it was stored in the session variables, but shows nothing at all.

The code from the login script:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller {

    /**
     * Index Page for this controller.
     */
    public function index() {
        $this->load->library('session');
        $BB_DATA = array();
        if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
            // SELECT username, password FROM Bacon or bacon-like product. <-- Fuck you #nobanchancom
            if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
                $q = sprintf('SELECT user_pk, username, pwhash, salt FROM tbl_user WHERE `username`=%s LIMIT 1;', $this->db->escape($_POST['username']));
                $records = $this->db->query($q);
                $username = $_POST['username']; // i added this
                if($records->num_rows() == 1) {
                    $record = $records->row();
                    $test_hash = hash_password($record->salt . $_POST['password']);
                    if($record->pwhash === $test_hash) {
                        $new_salt = generate_salt();
                        $new_hash = hash_password($new_salt . $_POST['password']);
                        $q = sprintf('UPDATE tbl_user SET `pwhash`="%s", `salt`="%s" WHERE `user_pk`="%s" LIMIT 1;', $new_hash, $new_salt, $record->user_pk);
                        if($updates = $this->db->query($q)) {
                            $BB_DATA['messages']['information'][] = "Login successful.";

                            //add custom data to session
                            $this->session->set_userdata('username', "$username");

                            //$this->session->set_userdata('some_name', 'some_value');
                            // redirect to /users/home/
                            redirect(site_url() . 'users/home/'); exit();
                        } else {
                            $BB_DATA['messages']['critical'][] = "You have logged in successfully, but an error has occurred during login.";
                        }
                    } else {
                        $BB_DATA['messages']['critical'][] = "That username/password does not match.";
                    }
                } else {
                    $BB_DATA['messages']['warning'][] = "That username/password does not exist.";
                }
            } else {
                $BB_DATA['messages']['warning'][] = "You must enter a username/password.";
            }
        }
        if(isset($_POST['register'])) {
            // Redirect to /register/
            redirect(site_url() . 'register/');
        }
        $this->load->view('login', $BB_DATA);
    }
}

/* End of file login.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/login.php */
```

And then here is the code for the users landing page:

```
<?php
class Users extends CI_Controller {

    public function home()
    {
        $this->session->userdata('username');
        require_once(APPPATH . 'views/header.inc.php');//header
            include(APPPATH . 'views/breadcrumbs.inc.php');//top breadcrumbs

            echo ' <h1>Welcome'.$username.',</h1>';
            //$username = $this->session->userdata('username');
            echo $this->session->all_userdata();
            //echo $username;
            include(APPPATH . 'views/breadcrumbs.inc.php');//bottom breadcrumbs
            require_once(APPPATH . 'views/footer.inc.php');//footer
    }



}

?>
```

In the login script, I call codeigniters session library-

> $this->load->library('session');

later, assuming everything went right, I add the $username variable to the session data. The user is redirected, and from there

> $this->session->userdata('username');
>   should re establish the variable. It does not.

Suggestions?

NOTE: So, I used `print_r(array_values($this->session->all_userdata()));` to print all the values in the array. It contained:

> Array ( [0] => 4c46f32b249ed55e8439152d63365fed [1] => 75.134.164.245
>   [2] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT; Win64; x64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101
>   Firefox/26.0 Waterfox/26.0 [3] => 1410568024 [4] => [5] => ottomatic )

So I am curious, Why did it add it as [5] rather than 'username'?

Comment: No that will not initialize a variable, you need to do $username = $this->session->userdata('username') . Also make sure the session library is loaded in the Users controller before anything

Comment: please see my edit. Also, according to the documentation, you don't call session library in each controller- codeigniter handles it's own sessions after the initial call. Or was that obsolete and never updated?

Comment: You're seeing 5 as the index because you're using array_values() instead of just print_r'ing the array itself. If the session library isn't auto-loaded (in config/autoload.php) then you need to load it in every controller in which you intend to use it.

Comment: Okay. Give me just a few minutes to update the autoload file and change to seeing the array itself so that I can see what I am working with.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a few tips in the right direction from @xd6_, I saw what was happening.

I had misread the documentation- you DO need to load the sessions on each page, unless it is in the /config/autoload.php array.

Once that was done, I was able to access the array element by name as

> $username = $this->session->userdata('username');